# How to set the screens size of Grid view to match all screen sizes?

Tags: android, xml, gridview

Here i have used a gridview but it is not changing according to the screen size.I think there is a problem with height.the xml used for gridview is given below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bg"
android:orientation="vertical" >




<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridView1"
     android:numColumns="3"
     android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
     android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
     android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
     android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
     >
</GridView>


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.assuretech.ku.HorizontalMenuBar
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
</RelativeLayout>
```

From what I can see. You need to close the RelativeLayout at the end. I've included my screenshot of your code with it closed. I changed the background to red to see the text.

Comment: i have closed the relativelayout tag....i missed it here..it has to set for all screensizes...

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for

> numColumns = "auto_fit"

as GridView attribute

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you must be using some layout to put your gridview in. Do the following:

Make height and width of the layout to fill parent:

android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
then, set height and width of your gridview to fill_parent as well.

Well, this is just a supposed solution that you might have been working this way

Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp">

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/grid_images"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:columnWidth="100dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="15dp">

    </GridView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Some explanation on your solution would be useful.